# (toc)dynnumwidth not working reliably in KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script

According to the [KOMA-Script documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), the option `dynnumwidth` in the `tocbasic`-style `toclines` (which is the template for the styles used by KOMA-Script’s sectioning commands in the table of contents) does the following:

> `dynnumwidth=switch`:
>   If the switch is active with style `tocline`, attribute `numwidth` is
>   ignored. Instead of that the maximum number width detected at the
>   previous LaTeX run increased by the value of `numsep` is used.

However, detection of the maximum number width does not seem to work reliably. Consider the two following MWE:

`test_1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[american]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \addsectiontocentry{Nr.~1}{Test1}
    \addsectiontocentry{Nr.~2}{Test2}
    \addsectiontocentry{Nr.~3}{Test3}
    \addsectiontocentry{Number~4}{Test4 (long)}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: First MWE: <code>dynnumwidth</code> broken]

`test_2.tex`:

```
\documentclass[american]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \addsectiontocentry{Nr.~1}{Test1}
    \addsectiontocentry{Nr.~2}{Test2}
    \addsectiontocentry{Number~3}{Test3 (long)}
    \addsectiontocentry{Number~4}{Test4 (long)}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Second MWE: <code>dynnumwidth</code> working]

So if I have three or more entries with short number widths, `dynnumwidth` does not detect the longer entry and chooses a `numwidth` value that is too small (MWE 1).
On the other hand, with two short and two long number width entries, the correct `numwidth` is determined (MWE 2).
Is this a bug or am I using `dynnumwidth` incorrectly?

I’m using TeX Live 2016/KOMA-Script v3.21.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me -- I get the same with three short sections and one large (after `\setcounter{section}{9999}`). Make a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Made a bug report, will update when the author gets to this one.

Comment: The bug will be fixed in the next KOMA-Script version 3.22. The bugfix can already be used with prerelease v3.22.2559, which can be installed from http://www.komascript.de/node/1801.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a bug report to KOMA-Script author Markus Kohm, who has confirmed that this is not working as intended.

As mentioned by [esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339371/51235#comment840247_339371), the bug has been fixed in [prerelease v3.22.2559](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801).
From the changelog:

> r2559 2016-12-02 09:03:11 +0100 kohm:
>
> - scrkernel-tocstyle.dtx: missing \relax added to fix dynnumwidth
>     feature

so it will be gone in KOMA-Script release v3.22.